# C/C++ speed ODE integration from Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I am numerically integrating some ODE's, e.g.

```
y'(t) = f(y(t), t)
```

This is easily done using for instance scipy's [integrate.ode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html). The function `f` is defined using standard Python, e.g.:

```
def f(y, t, k):
    return -k*y**3
```

My understand is that this means that the fortran/C implementation used by integrate.ode must do call-backs to Python all the time and this can be quite slow. **My question is whether there is a way to avoid this?**

Preferably I am looking for a package that lets me inline in my Python code a C-snippet, e.g.:

```
double f(double y, double t, double k) {
    return -k*pow(y,3);
}
```

Is there any ODE integrator library for Python that allows this?

I know there are packages like [scipy.weave](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/weave.html) that could be used to inline C code in Python, but I can't see an easy way to interface with integrate.ode. In all cases I think interfacing will have to go through a Python function call.

Inline C-code like this exist in other libraries such as [fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.5.0/python/programmers-reference/functions/expression/Expression.html), where `Expression` allow jit compiled C code.

Comment: I think you're in luck - [recent changes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.19.0.html#foreign-function-interface-improvements) in scipy 0.19 let you pass a compiled Cython function to `scipy.ode`. I've not actually used it myself though so can't easily provide a useful working example...

Comment: Thank you @DavidW. This is very usefull! I'm excited to see that coming to scipy. However, it seems to not be implemented for [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) yet, but only for [quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) (see descriptions of `func` in the documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a scikit devoted to this that extends the capabilities of `scipy.integrate`.

It is available here: https://github.com/bmcage/odes

The documentation contains an example of ODE integration sped up by implementing the right hand side in Cython: https://github.com/bmcage/odes/blob/master/docs/ipython/Cython%20cvode%20speedup.ipynb

As DavidW mentions, there is a new feature in SciPy to implement compiled style callbacks but only the quadrature routines can make use of it at this time.